# How to set the Corner of ControlFx SpreadsheetView

Tags: java, javafx, spreadsheet, controlsfx

I've looked for a while and can't find a way to set the corner label of the SpreadsheetView by ControlsFX for JavaFx.

I would like to put text there as a header for the row names.

https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/index.html?org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html

[Link to Image pointing to the corner label in question that needs to be with some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf51Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to tweak that particular "corner label". But we can modify the API in a future version in order to have that possibility.

You can open a enhancement in our github : https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx